# C# User keystrokes not registered

Tags: c#, input

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to make the user able to move a label using WASD, however it does not seem to work, I've lurked the internet for an answer with no hope. For the record I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

This is the user key detection method

```
internal class Input
    {
        private static Hashtable keyTable = new Hashtable();

        public static bool KeyPressed(Keys key)
        {
            if (keyTable[key] == null)
                return false;
            return (bool)keyTable[key];
        }
        public static void ChangeState(Keys key, bool state)
        {
            keyTable[key] = state;
        }
    }
```

And the code for actually moving stuff on a keystroke

```
private void moveObject(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            {
                if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.A))
                {
                    label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X - 1, label1.Location.Y);
                    MessageBox.Show("test", "test");
                }
                if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.D))
                {
                    label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X +1, label1.Location.Y);
                }
                if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.S))
                {
                    label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X, label1.Location.Y-1);
                }
                if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.W))
                {
                    label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X, label1.Location.Y+1) ;
                }
            }
```

It seems to me like it should work on paper, but it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: The _moveObject_ is the event handler for what control?

Comment: Honestly I don't know that much what I am doing, specifically I am not really familiar with the english terms of programming, so what does "what control" mean exactly?

Comment: I think what @Steve is getting at is what calls moveObject.

Comment: _moveObject_ is an event handler (from its arguments). This means that this code is called when an object on your interface raises an event (a user interact with the interface like typing a key) But to be called this event handler should be associated to the event or through code or through the designer. The controls are the elements of your interface (forms, button textboxes etc)

Comment: I see, but well I don't know how to do that, I thought this was enough, since my previous mini projects worked fine like this but not this time.

Comment: We don't even know what kind of UI are you using. Is this a WinForms(WPF project or an ASP.NET kind?

Comment: Oh, alright, it's WinForms I assume, I don't know what wpf/asp.net is. Sorry for my lack of general knowledge but I'm new to this. edit : it doesn't actually give me any errors if that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the moveObject method and find all references, this will help you find which event this method "handles". Additionally you can also add a break point in the method and perform the "event" to see if this method is actually called.

Comment: seems like it's not called, breakpoint gets stuck at the first '{', and the references it finds is "EventArgs e", i'll just give up on this, how do i close it?

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes you are using WinForms.*

Why don't you just use the built-in event? For the `Form` class there is a [`KeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown?view=netframework-4.7.2) event. Then you can use the [`KeyEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2) class' [`KeyCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode?view=netframework-4.7.2) property, which returns which key has been pressed.

Now that you have what key was pressed, use a switch/case block, to seperate actions based on the pressed key. (Just remember that every case block needs to end with the `break;` statement.) Every case's argument will be tested against the switch argument. If they are the same, that given case block will run. Otherwise, that said case block is skipped. For example, if you press the 'A' button, only the `case Keys.A` block will run.

Then use the [`Top`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.top?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.left?view=netframework-4.7.2) properties of the Label, to move the Label around.
e.g. if you press W, it should move up by 1 pixel, meaning the `Top` property should decrease by 1. (`Top` is the distance of the Label from the top of the window, `Left` is the distance from its left.)

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode) {
         case Keys.W: { 
             label1.Top -= 1;
             break;
         }
         case Keys.A: { //do stuff on A button }
         case Keys.S: { //do stuff on S button }
         case Keys.D: { //do stuff on D button }
         default: { break; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I can't test it currently but this seems to have the missing details other stack overflow answers I've found, will try to remember.

Comment: Okay, sorry but this still doesn't work, I'm gonna give up on this project.